# how to fix the error 500

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I installed Apache, PHP and MySQL in Windows 10 and edit config file also. I made change all things which are required like Directory root and add php module and Change `AllowOverride` and also enable its `LoadModule` and also enable extensions in `php.ini` file.

I keep my "apache" and "php" folder under `C:/intel`. All the installation is correct and also working nice (php files are running well) but when I run php file which contains mysqli function browser shows error:

> failed to load resources Internal server Error 500

How to fix it.Where am I doing wrong?

Note: I put "apache" and "php" folder under `C:/` its working nice all php files run which contain MySQL function also.

Comment: Check apache's error logs.

Comment: Go check in your php.ini files and make sure that you have set the mysqli extension to work

Comment: i enabled extension =php_mbstring.dll and extension=php_mysqli.dll .. Just remove ; beginning of these name

Comment: Actually the same setup is working when i put apache and php folder under c:/ directory..

Comment: Check the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll advice you install the XAMPP package which comprises of Apache, MySQL/MariaDB, PHP, Perl.
The installation is easy. It will save you all the stress and headache.
See here [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)